# Float Returns 0

Tags: c

EDIT #3: So when I compile with gcc, it all works fine. It only gives me 0 if I use clang (version 3.0). I'm so confused as to why clang wouldn't work for this since it seems relatively simple.

EDIT #2: Okay, so I've confirmed thanks to everyone that the code does work, but it's probably the environment. I'm doing all this in Ubuntu on an ARM Samsung Chromebook (through chroot actually). I'm using clang 3.0 (with only -o flag) to compile everything. I'm typing everything in vim. Is it because I'm on ARM that this is happening?

I've been staring at this for two hours and can't catch my mistake. Float just seems to return 0.000000 no matter what I do. I've tried dividing by 10000.0, storing 10000 in a variable of type float, of type double as well.

I've even written a tiny program that only had a variable of type float with 1.1 stored and then a printf("%f", variable) and it printed 0.000000.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the 1.1 was just there because I was just testing float.. I know I have to divide by 10000, haha.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool diceRoll (int a)
{
    int n = 0;
    int b = 0;
    while(n < 1) {
        b = rand() % 12;
        if(b == a || b == 6) n++;
    }
    if(b == 6) return false;
    else return true;
}


int main (void)
{
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL));
    int a, n, house, player;
    float houseWinRate, playerWinRate;
    house = 0;
    player = 0;
    float total = 1.1;

    for(n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
        a = rand() % 12;
        if(a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 11) {
            house++;
        }
        else if(a == 6 || a == 10) {
            player++;
        }
        else {
            if(diceRoll(a) == true) player++;
            else house++;
        }
    }
    printf("%i, %f\n", house, total);
    houseWinRate = house / total;
    playerWinRate = player / total;

    printf("The house has %i points. That's a winrate of %f.\n", house, houseWinRate);
    printf("The player has %i points. That's a winrate of %f.\n", player, playerWinRate);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For me It is 1.1 : `5377, 1.100000`

Comment: The program looks fine. Perhaps your environment? Do you have multiple compilers?

Comment: I'm doing this on an ARM based Samsung Chromebook running Ubuntu. Would that have any effect on it? I've been literally staring at my code for hours.. It'd be nice to know that I'm not just crazy..

Comment: http://codepad.org/r0MeQS0e   `5377, 1.100000`

Comment: What is the exact output you see from the program?

Comment: Okay, I just used codepad with my final code and it gave me the results I needed (http://codepad.org/ypH6CFFa).

But when I run it on my Chromebook, this is what I get (http://imgur.com/0OA8LY3)

Comment: If `float f = 1.1f; printf("%f\n", f);` really prints 0, then the problem isn't your code. It's your environment. You didn't provide much information about it. What compiler are you using? What version? What's your host OS? What's the CPU of the target device? Does it support floating point? If not, are you using a floating point emulation library?

Comment: I've updated the OP with more information about my environment now.

Comment: What command did you use to compile your code? Are you sure you're actually running the code you've posted, and not an earlier version?

Comment: On a probably-unrelated note, `double` is generally a better idea than `float`, due to precision issues.

Comment: clang craps.c -o craps

And yeah, I'm positive I compiled before I ran. Even with the test program, I just did "clang test.c" and then "./a.out" and the test program still spit out 0 so I'm sure it's not because I just run an older version.

Comment: I don't see the line corresponding to `printf("%i, %f\n", house, total);` in your screenshot

Comment: @Nirk: I removed that because it was just a line to see what the computer saw. I removed it when I saw that the program does indeed run fine everywhere except my Chromebook.

Comment: @user2797058 what does `printf("%f %f\n", (float)house, ((float)house) / total);` give you?

Comment: @Nirk it gave me 0.000000 942162247.....HUGE number (maybe like 60 digits if I'm eyeballing it right). Ended in .000000.

Comment: It looks like the conversion to float is failing.  What does `printf("%f\n", house + 0.1);` give you

Comment: When I compile with gcc, it gives 5478.100000. When I compile with clang, it gives 0.000000.

Comment: Try the simplest test case, when nothing works, blame the compiler. That's the life of programmers, lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[RESOLVED]** OP verified this code to be working with gcc on Chromebook.

This is not an answer, but stuff here cannot be posted to the comment.

Can you try `*100` before `/total`? (referring to your [codepad code](http://codepad.org/ypH6CFFa))

Also try the simplest test app to test only arithmetic part (also using double for `houseWinRate`):

```
int main (void)
{
    // using hardcoded value here
    int house = 5492;
    int player = 4508;

    double houseWinRate = 0.0;
    float playerWinRate = 0.0;
    float total = 10000.0;


    houseWinRate = ((double)house / total) * 100.0;
    playerWinRate = (player * 100.0) / total;

    printf("[double] The house has %i points. That's a winrate of %lf percent.\n", house, houseWinRate);
    printf("[mul first] The player has %i points. That's a winrate of %f percent.\n", player, playerWinRate);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I did what you asked (after changing your program a bit since you didn't declare player or house but that's all I did) and it still gives 0.000000.

Moving the * 100 doesn't change anything either.

Comment: LOL, I think I'm really tired. Just tried gcc and it gives the proper code. But when I compile with clang, it doesn't work properly. Why is that?

Comment: Hmmm, we programmers call this a BUG!!!! File it to the clang team. They may give use some useful advice (it could be some compiler flags that have to be given).

Comment: I'm adding this info to my answer then.

Comment: I can't believe I spent so much time staring at this code when it was actually working. Thank god for SO and its users like you!

Clang's stable version is 3.3 but my version is 3.0. Should I still file a bug report at this point?

Comment: We usually test the latest stable before filing a bug. Otherwise it will be rejected immediately with comment `fixed in latest version`. It's also users like you that keeps our tools improving. Thanks for your time on this.